# Корректный деплой spring boot на tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

Есть приложение Spring Boot, которое запускается и работает корректно. Настроил его для генерации war-ника согласно документации Spring. При деплое на сервер приложение получает адрес localhost:8080/sample/, после чего ломаются все запросы (например, после ввода логина/пароля идет запрос по адресу localhost:8080/login, что приводит к 404, и это логично). Каким образом это фиксить?

Осложняется всё тем, что это тестовое задание при трудоустройстве, и необходимо независимо запускать на tomcat.

Comment: в html как вы указываете путь на страницу логина, через слеш или нет(`href='login'` или `href='/login'`)? Для форм аналогично. И дополните вопрос, используете jsp, ajax или что-то еще?

Comment: @MrFylypenko В форме логина `action="/login"`, использую Thymeleaf, ajax в js.

Comment: задеплоейте приложение в рут и тогда оно со 100% гарантией будет работать, если у вас оно работает как Spring boot. Потому что в spring boot приложении по умолчанию используется рут паф. А здесь при деплоее у вас поменялся паф на /sample.

Comment: @Дмитрий назовите свой варник `ROOT.war` , приложение задеплоится в `localhost:8080/` это самый короткий путь, чтоб все работало. А что касается путей, то можете [посмотреть тут](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) примерно в коде должно быть написано в стиле thymeleaf: `<form th:action="@{/order/processOrder}">` . Хоть с  thymeleaf не знаком, но стоит проверить начало путей с `/` и без него.

Comment: @MrFylypenko спасибо, капнул в сторону Thymeleaf, и действительно - можно обернуть все ссылки как `th:href="@{/login}"`, после чего все ссылки будут работать, как следует.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что вам нужно указать паф у всех контроллеров в виде  - "/endpoint".
Это означает что реквест будет идти по localhost:8080/{имя_артефакта}/endpoint.
Если указать паф без "/", например  - "endpoint", тогда запрос будет идти по  localhost:8080/endpoint.